# Unable to use API call in HERE SDK (Android)

Tags: here-api, here-android

I am trying to use the HERE SDK Explorer Edition for Android and I need to make an API call to the HERE routes API. The API call itself works in the web browser, but I get "Routing error: 1, exception: Requested resource not found, error code: 404" when trying to use it in the Android application.

The API call is: "https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apikey=-YOUR_API_KEY&origin=52.524465%2C13.382334&destination=52.525301%2C13.399844&return=polyline%2Csummary%2Cactions%2Cinstructions%2CrouteHandle&transportMode=car"

as shown in the documentation: "https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-explore/4.13.5.0/dev_guide/topics/routing.html#import-routes-from-other-services"

The code I have tried to use the API in the SDK is as follows:

```
 routingEngine.importRoute(
                        new RouteHandle(apiCall),
                        new RefreshRouteOptions(TransportMode.CAR),
                        new CalculateRouteCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onRouteCalculated(@Nullable RoutingError routingError, @Nullable List<Route> routes) {
                                if (routingError == null) {
                                    Route route = routes.get(0);
                                    showRouteDetails(route);
                                    showRouteOnMap(route);
                                    getManeuverInstructions(route);
                                    logRouteViolations(route);
                                } else {
                                    Log.e("Error while calculating a route:", routingError.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-explore/4.13.5.0/dev_guide/topics/routing.html#import-routes-from-other-services):

You need to replace YOUR_API_KEY with the actual key you have in use.

Secondly, take a look at this code snippet:

```
routingEngine.importRoute(new RouteHandle("routeHandleStringFromBackend"),
                      new RefreshRouteOptions(TransportMode.CAR),
                      new CalculateRouteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onRouteCalculated(@Nullable RoutingError routingError, @Nullable List<Route> list) {
            if (routingError == null) {
                Route newRoute = list.get(0);
                // ...
            } else {
                // Handle error.
            }
        }
    });
```

The `RouteHandle("routeHandleStringFromBackend")` requires to set a string: Replace "routeHandleStringFromBackend" with the actual handle you have in use, for example: `RouteHandle("FGFHJG454fFD_MYHANDLE")`

Note that all of this is only meant to import existing routes you have calculated via web. If you just want to calculate a route, please try to read this example:

```
Waypoint startWaypoint = new Waypoint(startGeoCoordinates);
Waypoint destinationWaypoint = new Waypoint(destinationGeoCoordinates);

List<Waypoint> waypoints =
        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(startWaypoint, destinationWaypoint));

routingEngine.calculateRoute(
        waypoints,
        new CarOptions(),
        new CalculateRouteCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onRouteCalculated(@Nullable RoutingError routingError, @Nullable List<Route> routes) {
                if (routingError == null) {
                    Route route = routes.get(0);
                    showRouteDetails(route);
                    showRouteOnMap(route);
                    logRouteViolations(route);
                } else {
                    showDialog("Error while calculating a route:", routingError.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

With this you do not need to initiate an "API call", you just use the HERE SDK to calculate a route - under the hood it will, however, contact a backend service.

On the other hand, you can also calculate routes with the [JavaScript API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/index.html) - via web. In order to use such routes with the HERE SDK you need to **import** them. For this you need to know the route handle which you can obtain from the JavaScript API.

Comment: I now see my mistake, I simply placed the API Call as the route handle but there is a routeHandle object in the response. My apologies for being so negligent.